# Why doesn't the nonconservative nature of the electric field pushing along the wire to produce the drift velocity violate Kirchhoff's voltage law?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields

Seemingly, the drift velocity is from the electric field pushing in the same direction of the (theoretical positive) current along all of the wire, but then this is a loop that is a not conservative  field (i.e. accelerating everywhere from the electric field along the loop), so why does Kirchoff's voltage rule apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that your loop is a battery connected by wires to one resistor. The E field inside the battery is, like a capacitor, opposite to the E field inside the wires, where the E field inside the wires is needed to set up the current as Ohm's Law $\vec J=\sigma \vec E$ says it has to be.

The voltage difference between the ends of the battery is one and the same; going from inside the battery gives opposite sign as going outside the battery, and so the loop integral cancels out. KVL happens to hold for this. Of course, you should always abandon KVL and go straight to Faraday's Law, which always holds. There is no time varying B fields here, so Faraday's Law says that KVL will hold.

Comment: In this case, however, isn't the voltage "drop" occurring through the electric field in the battery in the opposite direction of the electric field in the loop of wire? Why do we say the voltage drop is in the resistor, then?

Comment: Well, it all depends upon which direction you are integrating. In the usual direction, we say that the voltage increases as you go along the battery and voltage drops in the resistor, whereas if you chose the opposite direction, then the voltage drops in the battery and increases over the resistor. The opposite direction is insane, so obviously we do not use it if we can avoid it.

Comment: The direction of the electric field is the same inside and outside the battery. It points from the cathode to the anode. The sign of the potential drop doesn't change because you are taking a path inside or outside the battery, it changes because for one part of the KVL loop you are going from cathode to anode and for the other part you are going from anode to cathode.

Comment: @ThePhoton is correct. The E field is always from positive terminal to negative terminal. It is just along the wires v.s. inside the battery we are seeing it from a different perspective and so that explains why I said opposite directions.

Answer (score -1):

> Seemingly, the drift velocity is from the electric field pushing in the same direction of the (theoretical positive) current along all of the wire, but then this is a loop that is a not conservative field ...

Kirchhoff's circuit laws apply only in the *lumped circuit approximation*.

The lumped circuit approximation requires that the physical loop formed by the circuit wires is small compared to the wavelength associated with the highest frequency signals present in the circuit. In this case, the effect of the magnetic field created by the current in the circuit (which would be a radiating EM field and a loss of energy from the circuit) is negligible.

But of course this is only an approximation. It is good enough to be used to design and analyze many useful circuits. But it is only an approximation and not an exact model of the real circuit.

We make similar approximations all the time in physics, for example when we neglect wind resistance in an analysis of pool balls moving on the table, or when we neglect friction in an analysis of weights balanced on a see-saw.

Comment: This is not an answer to the problem that the OP is trying to raise. The lumped circuit approximation works in this case beautifully, but if the OP is confused about the signs, it would not help to say that this approximation works.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent, the question asks about a nonconservative field, not about signs. I answered the question that was asked.

Comment: The situation that the OP was asking about was about an E field around a loop. The OP was confused, thinking that it is non-conservative, when in fact it is. What is missing from the OP's original statement is that, by assuming a constant drift velocity (rather, by omission of stating that the drift velocity is changing with position or time), the OP is really talking about the constant DC situation. It is not a case with increasing magnetic field anywhere.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent, they asserted that the field is non-conservative. The only way that could be is if there is a changing magnetic flux through the loop. I explained why that isn't important in this kind of problem. I agree they are confused. You made a leap to assume they had made a sign error in their KVL calculation. I made a leap to guess why they were worried about non-conservative fields. When the question is this unclear, I don't go around down-voting people for making different guesses than me about what the OP is confused about.

Comment: The OP agreed with my assertion of what they were confused about before you wrote your answer. Even in the case whereby you are correct, that there is a time-varying magnetic field and so there really is a non-conservative electric field, there is no sense in which "that isn't important in this kind of problem"; a proper answer would then have to actually work out where that comes from and what everything means. You did not even manage to explain why it wont be important from within suitable assumptions of the system. It simply isn't an answer to anything near the question.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent, OP is so confused that I don't trust them to know what they're confused about. And your answer was not posted when I began composing mine.